backdrop-filter:blur affecting full width/height elements in Chrome?
I’ve noticed an issue with backdrop-filter: blur in Chrome. As soon as an element in front of the blurred area has full width or height, it seems to get blurred (edges) as well.
This affects combinations of  bottom: 0; top: 0; or left: 0; right: 0; width:100%; height: 100%.
So far, I’ve only been able to observe this problem in Chrome. Is there a way to avoid this behavior?
Screenshot: Chrome shows blurred edges
Screenshot: Firefox is fine
<div style=" position:fixed; margin:0; left:0; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; z-index: 10;backdrop-filter: blur(8px);-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px);"
></div>

<div style="position:fixed; left:0; top:0; bottom:0; background-color:red; width: 100px; z-index: 999;">
</div>

Codepen
I did notice that applying transform cancels the effect, but only as long as the element is actually changed. For example, transform: translateX(-1px) works in combination with left: 0; but not with left: 1px;.
